# What is sp equal to when you return from a far procedure with instruction ret

Tags: assembly, x86-16

Specifically in 8086 assembly, if SS = AC8D and SP = 7A75, what SP will be equal after returning from a call to a far procedure with ret (instructin code CB).

Comment: Depends on how much arguments the procedure has... Please try to make answerable questions.

Comment: @m0skit0 The procedure doesn;t have any arguments

Comment: SP = 7A75 when? Entry of procedure? Exit of procedure? Are entry-exit protocols finished?

Comment: @m0skit0, also ss = AC8D, no other information is given.

Comment: Then check Jens Björnhager's answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A far return pops off both IP and CS from the stack, so SP will increase by 2*2 bytes.

Comment: Note that there is a callee-pops `retf imm16` form available (https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ret), so for example `retf 8` would increase SP by 4 + 8 = 12.  This question is only uniquely answerable when the calling convention uses caller-pops, so functions use plain `retf`, without an immediate, but in the general case you can't tell.